# Session in API Controllers. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, сессия

Хочу работать с сессией в API контроллере через вспомогательный класс. Но не знаю как, сессия всегда `null`.

Вспомогательный класс:

```
public class SessionHelper
{
    private HttpSessionState session; // это?
    private HttpSessionStateBase session; // или это?

 public SessionHelper()
    {
        session = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
    }

    public void AddValue(string name, object value)       
    {
        this.session.Add(name, value);
    }

    public void RemoveValue(string name)
    {
        this.session.Remove(name);
    }

    public bool FindValue(string name)
    {
        if (this.session[name] != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object GetValue(string name)
    {
        return this.session[name];
    }

    public void UpdateValue(string name, object value)
    {
        RemoveValue(name);
        AddValue(name, value);
    }
}
```

API Controller:

```
public class VocabularyAPIController : ApiController
{
    private VocabularyManager vocabularyManager;
    private SessionHelper session;

    public VocabularyAPIController()
    {
        this.vocabularyManager = new VocabularyManager();
        this.session = new SessionHelper();
    }
    public WordDto[] GetWords(int id)
    {
        if (this.session.FindValue("words"))
            return this.session.GetValue("words") as WordDto[];

        else
            this.session.AddValue("words", this.vocabularyManager.GetWords(id));

        return this.session.GetValue("words") as WordDto[];
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void UpdateResult(WordDto[] words)
    {
        this.session.UpdateValue("words", words);
    }
}
```

Какой тип сессии использовать? И какой бы я тип не использовал `session` всегда пустая. Как правильно обращаться к сессии не из контроллера? Если она всегда `null`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15038669/4594225